# Why use ReLu in the final layer of Neural Network?

Tags: relu

It is recommended that we use ReLu in the final layer of the neural network when we  are learning regressions. 
It makes sense to me, since the output from ReLu is not confined between 0 and 1.

However, how does it behave when x < 0 (ie when ReLu output is zero). Can y(the result of regression) still be lesser than 0?

I believe, I am missing a basic mathematical concept here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You typically use:

- A linear layer for regression in order to get a continuous value
- Softmax for classification where you want a probability distribution of classes

But these aren't set in stone. If you know your output value for a regression should only be positive, why not use a ReLu? If the output of your classification isn't a probability distribution (ex, which classes exists) you could just as easily use a sigmoid.